# New to using Anaconda + Python + JupyterNote book: Obtaining FileNotFoundError

Tags: pandas, csv, import, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter netbook is unable to read my csv files. I'm trying to copy and merge several spreadsheets but Jupyter is unable to read the csv file.

Obtaining error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Parcelbook.csv' does not exist: b'Parcelbook.csv

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in 

_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    427 
    428     # Create the parser.
--> 429     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    430 
    431     if chunksize or iterator:
```

I have a mac, running Python 3.7 + Anaconda, I just installed and set this up last night, and not sure if I may have skipped a step- not sure if I was suppose to set a file path directory.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Parcelbook.csv") 
df
```

**code error:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Parcelbook.csv' does not exist: b'Parcelbook.csv'
```

Anyhelp is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Parcelbook.csv" is in the current directory? but maybe you should set the path of the csv file

Comment: I would type the full path for the file. Also you could try to change filename to very simple (data.csv) to avoid typos. Usually file should be in the same directory where you started jupyter notebook and you should be able to see it in you browser where notebook is running. Also in notebook you can use !-mark to make shell commands for instance !ls -l shows the files in your current directory.

Comment: @lostCode, Yes, Parcelbook.csv is in the file directory- currently /User/Name/Parcelbook.csv, I can't seem to resolve. I would love to change my file path directory, but don't know how.

Comment: @user2198210 I tried the full path, I think it's termed "Absolute"- I may be wrong- as I've been reading about this since last night, and just about had it- anyways; I changed the file location, file name several times, but still not reading it. The file name was longer- and I condensed it like 3 times, and even changed the located several times, but no luck, and when I do the gwd even after trying to change it, it still shows up the same. How do I change my working directory to where my files are on a mac?